# Ensuring Programs Run In Ordered Sequence

Tags: bash

This is my situation:

I want to run Python scripts sequentially in sequence, starting with scriptA.py. When scriptA.py finishes, scriptB.py should run, followed by scriptC.py. After these scripts have run in order, I need to run an rsync command.

I plan to create bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
python scriptA.py
python scriptB.py
python scriptC.py
rsync blablabla
```

Is this the best solution for perfomance and stability ?

Comment: Your script is already running them in sequence you want. If you can describe a little more what you want it would be better to get relevant answers.

Comment: for @anubhava and downvotes , please read the pjmorse answer

Comment: If you want to create a bash script, then you want to have the first line of the file read `#!/bin/bash`. As it is now, it will run in the Bourne shell.

Comment: ...although for a script as simple as this, it's unlikely that will make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run a command only after the previous command has completed successfully, you can use a logical AND:

```
python scriptA.py && python scriptB.py && python scriptC.py && rsync blablabla
```

Because the whole statement will be true only if all are true, bash "short-circuits" and only starts the next statement when the preceding one has completed successfully; if one fails, it stops and doesn't start the next command.

Is that the behavior you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

If you have some experience with python it will almost certainly be better to write a python script that imports and executes the relevant functions from the other script. That way you will be able to use pythons exceptions handling. Also you can run the rsync from within python.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do not have much experience using python unfortunately

Comment: well then the answer from @pjmorse this the best solution for you